# How can I port forward from the router to a server with NordVPN?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nordvpn

I've got a home server and it has NordVPN running on it.

Then I've got port forwarding rules in my router to point to the server on port 80/443, so I can look at my security cameras.

That all works fine with NordVPN off, as soon as I turn NordVPN I can't connect externally, it times out.

I've got this in the whitelist, but doesn't seem to help:

```
Allowlisted subnets:
    192.168.1.0/24
```

How can I connect to the server externally (router's public IP) while having NordVPN running?

Comment: Can the server ping the router while the VPN is running? Can you connect to the server from the local network while the vpn is running? If not, check if your service is listening on all interfaces (not bound to just the vpn adapter). If the source IP is the router, then you may need to manually add a route for `192.168.1.0/24`

Comment: You'll probably need policy routing for this.

Answer (score 0):

While NordVPN is running, your computer's IP is not in the range of
`192.168.1.x`, but is in whatever network that NordVPN creates,
perhaps `10.x.x.x`. You can't connect to it from the router,
because it's on a disjointed network.

The NordVPN documentation describes a
[Meshnet](https://nordvpn.com/meshnet/) feature as:

> Meshnet is a way to safely access other devices, no matter where in the world they are. Once set up, Meshnet functions just like a secure local area network (LAN) — it connects devices directly.

See also the post
[How to start using Meshnet](https://meshnet.nordvpn.com/getting-started/how-to-start-using-meshnet) :

> The best way to become familiar with  is to start using it right away. Luckily, Meshnet is not complicated to set up — all you need to do is  and enable Meshnet on each of your devices. They will automatically discover and connect to each other. Then you can begin using the network to securely access resources, share files, and collaborate with others.

The solution is then to install NordVPN on your exterior computer
and enable Meshnet on both computers. They should then,
by the documentation, be able to discover each other.

(I have no experience with NordVPN, so can only go by the documentation.)

Comment: The PC absolutely still is in the original subnet, otherwise it could not connect to the internet. That's not the issue. Routing + possibly the VPN killswitch is.

Comment: @DanielB: Routing usually solves such problems of disjointed subnets, but specifically NordVPN has a much better and easier solution. Routing may not be so easy in a consumer router.

Comment: It’s not the router that has to do the proper routing here. It’s the home server itself. It has to send response traffic not through the VPN, but around it.

Comment: Response to a message coming through the router, but how does it get to the server?